# Memory error while running for iOS [AddressSanitizer CHECK failed] [FLUTTER] [IOS]

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, flutter-ios

### **Scenario:**

I have this app that I am building for quite a while now. But abruptly I started getting errors while running for the iOS version. I got errors on the local network connection which I did search for and found a solution online to create two files `Info-debug.plist` and `Info-release.plist` replacing info.plist. Which I resolved and got another issue (which is the main issue posting here). *Just in case any need for what resolution I've gone through, please check below. Else, skip over the optional part to the **Main Issue**.*

**[OPTIONAL] Previous issue (local network connection) fix:**

1. Created two files `Info-debug.plist` and `Info-release.plist` replacing `info.plist` and configured the same in build settings in Xcode.

**IMAGE:**

[image: Point 1 Image]

2. Added two new fields for `Info-debug.plist` -> `NSBonjourServices` key with `_dartobservatory._tcp` as value & secondly `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` key.

**IMAGE:**

[image: Point 2 Image]

> Post this, I haven't got any errors related to the local network. But
> new issue arose, which I really TBH don't have any idea if it is
> related to the above fix or not [Added for reference]

### **Main issue:**

There seems to be a memory issue which TBH I am not still able to relate to or understand with any online resources.

The error I am getting (see below):

Textual:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 9B88DRXV3V
Xcode build done.                                           672.9s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:65213/J9NnVgwaIYY=/ws
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...

==837==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/clang_compiler_rt/clang-1300.0.29.30/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:191 "((0)) == ((sigaltstack(&altstack, &oldstack)))" (0x0, 0xffffffffffffffff)
    <empty stack>
Warning: hit breakpoint while running function, skipping commands and conditions to prevent recursion.
AddressSanitizer report breakpoint hit. Use 'thread info -s' to get extended information about the report.
* thread #24, name = 'DartWorker'
    frame #0: 0x000000010a973328 libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie()
libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie:
->  0x10a973328 <+0>:  pacibsp
    0x10a97332c <+4>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30
    0x10a973330 <+8>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x10a973334 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]

Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Image form (for better format understanding):

[image: Image Form of ERROR]

---

### **Things I've tried already:**

- Cleaning flutter project (`flutter clean`)
- Removing `podfile.lock` file and re-running `pod install`

It was working well until last night but don't know what's the issue here is. Thanks!

Comment: What is `_dartobservatory._tcp` used for? IIRC, The TCP protocol is supposed to be used for `Hot Reload`. If occupied by you there may be a possible memory leak and lead to `AddressSanitizer` warning

Comment: Hii @Sunbreak thanks for the message, previously I was getting the network issue on iOS and after lookup, found out to add `_dartobservatory._tcp` with `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription`. Which fixed the issue, but started with the new error of memory leak. I wasn't getting any feedback upon this, and therefore had to port the code to new application.

Comment: did you find any solution for open failed for data file ? I have the same issue